# Theory of "integration" on sets of measure zero (the measure zero sets are with respect to Lebesgue measure )

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose we have Lebesgue measurable set E. Let F be a subset of E with measure zero with respect to the Lebesgue measure on E. My question is, can we construct a "reasonable" integration theory on the set F that can be extended to the set E ? In other words, what are the alternative theory of integrations on a set of measure zero (the measure zero sets are with respect to Lebesgue measure ) ?

Comment: I don't understand the question, perhaps you could elaborate more

Comment: Measure zeros sets are kind of "bad" sets (here it is F) where Lebesgue measure vanishes, my question is, can we construct a non-vanishing "good" measure on F such that the integration with respect to that measure is non zero on F and with respect to the same hypothetical measure on F, an Integration theory be constructed on the larger set E ?

Comment: So, for example, you're asking what it takes to recover the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb R$ from the counting measure on $\mathbb Z$?

Comment: Partially yes, but I am looking for a "big picture", for say rationals have zero measure  inside reals with respect to Lebesgue so, I want an Integration theory, entirely built over rationals and non-zero and will give a well defined meaning over reals, and of course the theory should be generalised in an appropriate sense whenever possible

Answer (score 0):

On many sets of measure zero, you can construct the "Hausdorff measure."  The Cantor set is a good example of such a set.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_measure

For countable sets like the rationals, I think measures absolutely continuous with respect to counting measure are all you are going to get.

Comment: Thank you, I do have some knowledge on Hausdorff measure, but I want to have a more general theory than that, as you can't apply "Hausdorff" measures without a metric ! More in some abstract setting so that I can apply the theme for general spaces .

Comment: So on locally compact topological groups, you get Haar measure.  And many other structures give rise to measures.  But if you have a set with no additional structure, then the only way to categorize the set is by cardinality.  Obviously sets like the Cantor set which have the same cardinality of the real numbers can be given any number of measures.  In fact the reals can have any number of weird measures placed upon them, simply by taking a non-trivial bijection between $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb R$ (or $\mathbb R^n$ is you like).

Comment: Suppose you are given an infinite set?  How do your make rigorous the notion that any element of the set can be picked with equal likelihood?  This is one of the central questions of Bayesian statistics.  Really, nobody has much of a clue.

Comment: Thank you for the information regarding Bayesian Statistics, actually I want to define a test function on certain set of measure zero within a larger space, I have a "theory of integration" in that set of measure zeo, but can't extend the theory on the larger set, as if a function h is defined over rationals, but if I integrate with respect to Lebesgue measure of reals, I can never get a non-zero value of the integral of h, so I need a way out, that is why the question

Comment: Can I try develop a theory similar Dirac distribution ? but still struggling with the meaning as the support of that "Dirac Distribution" might be uncountable as Cantor Set, and I don't know any theory to handle such situations

Comment: Suppose you have two sets $A,B \subset \mathbb R$ which are measure zero, and have the same cardinality.  Then you can find a measure preserving bijection $\mathbb R$ onto itself which maps the set $A$ to the set $B$.  Thus there is nothing about the structure of Lebesgue measure that confers any natural measure structure on sets of measure zero.

Comment: Ok, it seems helpful, can you please provide any related reference ?

Comment: The idea is to find a set $C$ that contains $A \cup B$ such that $C \setminus (A \cup B)$ has cardinality the same as $A$, and $C$ has measure zero.  Then find a bijection $\phi:C \to C$ that takes $A$ to $B$.  Then define $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ as the identity on $\mathbb R \setminus C$, and $\phi$ on $C$.

Comment: Thank you Stephen, you really are helpful.

Comment: I'm thinking on my feet a bit here.  Probably it would be adequate to take $C = A \cup B$.  I just need to be a bit careful if the cardinality of $A \setminus B$ is different from $B \setminus A$.